# Maven/Gradle container fails to build project on internal k8s cluster

Tags: maven, gradle, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to create sample jenkins pipeline to build maven/gradle based application on internal kubernetes cluster. I have setup proxy through environment variable, on addition I have inserted proxy parameters in gradle.properties file too. Whenever I tries to build an application through `gradle build` It fails with an error `Java: READ ONLY FILE SYSTEM` . I searched online and found that due to different UID on `jnlp` and `gradle` container, `Gradle` fails to access `/home/jenkins/` workspace. I inserted `Pod Security Policy` parameter on the pod and tried to executed all the container with same UID `1000`, still It fails. I am still not sure exact root cause of this weird issue.

Reference Link: https://akomljen.com/set-up-a-jenkins-ci-cd-pipeline-with-kubernetes/

I am using **Jenkins official helm chart** to deploy jenkins on the cluster.

```
def label = "maven-${UUID.randomUUID().toString()}"

podTemplate(label: label, containers: [
  containerTemplate(name: 'gradle', image: 'gradle:latest', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat',
  envVars: [
    envVar(key: 'http_proxy',value: 'www.xxx:8080'),
    envVar(key: 'https_proxy',value: 'www.xxx:8080')
    ])
  ]) {

  node(label) {
    stage('Build a Gradle project') {
      git 'SOME GRADLE PROJECT REPO.'
      container('gradle') {
          sh 'gradle build --stacktrace'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Consider the above sample example (assume `jenkinsci/jnlp-slave:latest` will be provisioned by Jenkins Default Pod template and will be attached to this pod)

Gradle Daemon will start and later fails with the following error.

```
Error resolving plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.1.4.RELEASE']
18:24:47.119 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration1'.
18:24:47.119 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    > java.io.IOException: Read-only file system
```

Comment: Where does this error actually come from? Can you give some more context where you see this and how it is triggered? Also, can you SSH to a node that would have run this and give the output of `mount -v` so we can rule out any actual filesystem full / issue?

Comment: Please see the edited post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. I was mounting secret volume inside /tmp/ directory and that's why entire container went on **READ ONLY FILE SYSTEM** mode. I still don't know why **jenkins workspace directory** went to **read only** mode as I mounted secret inside **/tmp** directory.